# i am able to prrint all data in table but one field i can not abble to print

Tags: swift, uitableview, alamofire

I am call api through alamofire and i am getting response perfectly and i am able to all data into label in tableview cell but there is one field in response that i can not able to print let me explain below

Response:

```
SUCCESS: {
    data =(
        {
            "from_id" = 77;
            "from_name" = Paresh;
            image = "https://www.kwikmypay.com/mode_share/modeshare_admin/assets/images/business/userNotFound.png";
            msg = hi;
            "msg_date" = "18-07-2018 05:54:40 am";
            "msg_id" = 1;
            "new_msg" = 37;
            "to_id" = 88;
            "to_name" = Mihir;
        }
```

from this response i am able to print all but there is one field "new_msg" that i can't able to print can any one explain me this problem below is my code

```
let serviceparam = ["user_id":u_id,"access_token":acc_tkn,"time_zone": currentTimeZone] as [String : Any]
        SVProgressHUD.show(withStatus: "Loading...")

        Alamofire.request(chatList, method: .post, parameters: serviceparam).responseJSON
            {
                response in

                print(response)
                let result = response.result

                if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>{
                    if let serlist = dict["data"]{

                        self.servicelist = serlist as! [AnyObject]
                        self.tbl_chatlist.reloadData()
                        //self.dropDown.items = categorylist as! [AnyObject] as! [String]
                    }
                }
             SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                //self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        }
```

my service list array is proprly fiil up and all data i get correctly but not able to print on label ca any one please help me

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "chatlistcell") as! ChatlistTableViewCell

         let f_name = servicelist[indexPath.row]["from_name"]
         let image = servicelist[indexPath.row]["image"]
         let date = servicelist[indexPath.row]["msg_date"]
         let newMSG = servicelist[indexPath.row]["new_msg"]
         let lastMsg = servicelist[indexPath.row]["msg"]
         cell.lblTime.text = date as? String
         cell.lblTitle.text = f_name as? String
         cell.lblMsgCount.text = newMSG as? String
         cell.lblLastMsg.text = lastMsg as? String

         let proimgurl = NSURL(string: image as! String)
         cell.img_logo.image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOf: proimgurl! as URL)! as Data)



        return cell
    }
```

Here is the code and i have one label lblMsgCount and in response there is one filed new_msg  that i can not able to print

Comment: "but not able to print on label" What label? Which value are you trying to print? Where is that code?

Comment: please add the code that retrieve data from the Dictionary

Comment: please check code i was edit it

Comment: Note: you should not decode JSON/dictionaries in `func tableView`. You should instead make objects (class/struct) from the JSON data as soon as you get it. Then you would easily access these objects in the tableview.

Comment: `new_msg` is that really a `String`? Can't it be a `Int`. Try: `if let newMessageInt = newMSG as? Int { cell.lblMsgCount.text = String(newMessageInt) } else if let newMessageStr = newMSG as? String { cell.lblMsgCount.text = newMessageStr }`

Comment: code looks ok . can you  call the reload of tableview  from main thraed    DispatchQueue_Main_async {   tableview.reload()   }

Comment: @Larme thank you its work fine now and thak you to all of who wish to help me

Comment: Still, please follow @Moritz suggestion (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439063/i-am-able-to-prrint-all-data-in-table-but-one-field-i-can-not-abble-to-print?noredirect=1#comment89848363_51439063) Use a custom class/struct that will handles theses cases.

Comment: Yes sure i will refer this

Comment: can you provide me example of class or struct because i am new to swift so